# How is a private broadcast channel protected by Laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

Within Laravel we do something like this to broadcast on a private channel:

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user-'.$this->user->id);
    }
}
```

Taking a closer look at the internals of `PrivateChannel`, it's simply prepending `private-` to the channel name.

How exactly is Laravel protecting the broadcast to only authorised users? I am using Redis rather than Pusher.

Comment: check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Comment: @SapneshNaik I am not using Echo at this moment. Anyone knows if this is necessary to protect the broadcast for specific users?